# PostgreSQL data recovery from a data directory which has some missing files

Tags: database, postgresql, data-recovery

In my Linux server I have PostgreSQL server in production. By any chance, some base/19180 and some other files are missing need to know any way to recover the data in any way.

I have to try to create new DB and use this directory as its data-dir but it's now working.

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is harder to read and understand, and it won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite for you to be SHOUTING at us when you're asking us for free help. Thanks.

Comment: *PostgreSQL server in production*? That should be easy - restore the files from your backup.

Comment: You forgot to mention the timeline and how you actually discovered that the files are missing. What type of object is covered by the missing files? Is the database still open?

Comment: we do not have any backup to restore... @KenWhite

Comment: After reinitializing DB with same directory. I am able to access the database and can see the size of DB, but I can't list the tables. Also when I am taking a dump of the database it shows missing file error.

Comment: You have a **production** database that is open enough for someone to  delete files and you're **not** backing it up?

Comment: Actually it's not open for everyone.. And I have this problem I know I don't have backups that's why I'm here for a solution. @KenWhite